# TV screen displaying bizarre text

Tags: display

I recently bought a Sony Bravia KDL-46EX728 screen and connected its HDM1 port to my computer. What I'm experiencing is distorted text that looks uncanny or even tiresome to look at as it basically looks like somebody didn't have enough ink to write.

Here's a view of it: 
[Screenshot of the Super User's main page in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK2BS.png)

If you could compare it to your screen then it might be even more obvious. Note that I didn't have that issue with the previous monitor so I really doubt that it might have something to do with my PC. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why fonts are so pixelated all of the sudden in windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1329616/why-fonts-are-so-pixelated-all-of-the-sudden-in-windows-10)

Comment: The above comment is a shot in the dark because *you haven't told us your OS*. What is the OS? To possibly explain the case of the previous monitor more information is needed. What was the previous monitor? Were you using its native resolution? What was the connection method? Please [edit] the question and add information.